# How can I trigger Azure Data Factory based on finishing Python script?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

**My Process:** I am extracting data from several on premise data sources using a Python script and loading them into Azure Blob Storage (raw data). After that, I am performing some ETL actions and use that result in PowerBI.

**What I want to achieve:** Currently I am able to do the ETL actions via a scheduled trigger in Azure Data Factory. However, I do not want to "lose" time and I would like the ETL to be triggered when the Python script is finished.

**Example:**: The Python script finishes at 8 AM in the morning. To build some margin, the scheduled Data Factory run is at 8.30 AM in the morning. This is the part where I am looking for some optimalisation so that the Data Factory run could start automatically after the Python script is finished.

(FYI: afterwards, the PowerBI reports refreshes automatically when the ETL actions are finished)

**With these tool(s):** Microsoft Azure Data Factory **or** Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics **or** Python?

**Your advice?**

Thanks a lot,
Kind regards

Comment: I found that I can do it with Event-based triggers in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below 2 approaches.

- **Using a Storage event trigger:** 
  Create a **new container** in blob storage. At the end of your python code, try to **upload a small text or any type of file to this container**. Add a ***Storage Event trigger for this container*** to your ETL pipeline. So, every time you complete the python script, it will upload the small file to that container **which triggers your ETL pipeline** in ADF.
- **Using a custom activity for the Python script:**
  Use the Custom activity in the ADF to execute your Python script. Then, ***add an Execute Pipeline activity for your ETL pipeline to the custom activity***. The custom activity will execute your code and ***after completion*** the execute pipeline activity will execute your ETL pipeline.
  Please refer this [material](https://azurelib.com/custom-activity-azure-data-factory/) from **azurelib** by **Deepak Goyal** to learn about executing python script using custom activity in ADF.

***NOTE:*** Use the custom activity approach only if you don't have any problems of accessing your on-prem files with python script anywhere in the Azure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh. I'm going with the Storage event trigger.